# Why is ZPL command ^PQ not working for multiples copies?

Tags: zpl

I've created my ZPL string and at the very end appended `^PQ`+numCopies. Debugger shows the whole string correct with `^PQ3` at the end.   But the printer only prints 1 copy.

Printer is a 110Xi4 and the onboard configuration shows it's in `ZPL II` mode.

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!  while I don't know ZPL itself, I wanted to make a comment on your question here.  If you surround your code text with the back tick marks (the one under the tilda) instead of quotes, the page will make it stand out more.  Also, while you believe your entire string to be correct, it will help people to answer your question if you give them the entire context of the question.  I believe you should edit this question and add the entire string that you are trying to get working.

Answer (score 10):

The `^PQ3` needs to be before the `^XZ`, not after it. the `^XZ` should be the last thing in the label

Answer (score 5):

There is a specific order in which ZPL commands need to be present in the document source in order for them to be effective (or for the document to print at all), as Ovi points out.

A ZPL document will look like (omit everything from the # to the end of that line):

```
^XA # start of document. Not optional
#optional one-off config stuff, for example:
^MNM # setting the media sensor for black bar
^PW200 # setting print width
# now include your actual label/document content
^FDText that is going to be printed^FS
^XZ # end of document. Not optional.
```

If you include the `^PQ3` after `^XZ`, the printer does not know what to do with that command. It's probably just discarded.

I will link to other examples and docs when I get some time.